# pandas dataframe: apply function to previous rows based on "current" row

Tags: pandas

I need to add a column to a `pandas` `dataframe` where each value is an accumulation of the previous rows. The challenge that I am facing is that the previous values are a function of the "current" value, so I am not able to use `cumsum()`.

The original code uses a double loop which I replaced with `apply` and the performance improved significantly even for a small dataset, but I feel that there should be a better approach. The code below shows the exact calculation that I need to perform.

```
def apply_formula(row, a, b): # where a and b are series

    c = 0
    cum = 0

    for j in range(0, row.name + 1): # iterate through the previous rows

        c = ((a[j] - a[j - 1]) / row.a) * log(row.b - b[j - 1]) / 2.3

        cum += c # accumulate

    return cum

df["new"] = df.apply(apply_formula, axis = 1, args = [df.a, df.b])
```

What `pandas` functions could help me solve this problem?

Comment: can you provide input & expected output dataframe?

Comment: the problem here is that the "simplified" calculation you present in your question can be done with a `cumsum` on the column b only. try `df['new_2'] = df.b.cumsum()/df.a*np.log(df.time)` and you will get the same value than `df['new']` (or at least on my sample it does with random values). Please provide the exact calculation if you want an answer you can use for your real case

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I just updated the question with the exact calculation that I need to perform.